# Is there a Chinese-Chinese dictionary api or database available that I can use in my own app?

Tags: dictionary, database

Is there a Chinese-Chinese dictionary api or database available?

I want to include it in an [app](http://readmersion.com) I am developing.

By "Chinese-Chinese" I mean that if you look up a word in Chinese you get a Chinese definition, not an English definition of a Chinese word.

I am looking for a word dictionary and/or a character dictionary.

I prefer a database or even a flat text file, but a web api might work.

Comment: A quick search got me this but I haven't tried. http://briskblog.eu.org/%E7%BC%96%E7%A8%8B/%E6%96%B0%E5%8D%8E%E5%AD%97%E5%85%B8%E3%80%90%E7%AE%80%E4%BD%93%E3%80%91%E3%80%81%E6%88%90%E8%AF%AD%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8%E3%80%81%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8-api%E5%85%AC%E5%BC%80%E6%B5%8B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this link to a bunch of StarDict dictionaries: http://download.huzheng.org/zh_CN/

You can convert these to text files in linux using `sudo apt install stardict-tools` and then run `stardict-editor`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might get this kind of database from some publication press if you are lucky, but it seems to be not an easy way.

Also, I didn't find any database or flat text with Open Source License from the Internet.

But here is a website which is quite clean and neat. http://www.zdic.net/

I tried to look up a single Chinese character(字), and the request link seems quite tidy. I tried 好 and it showed http://www.zdic.net/z/17/js/597D.htm ,where `597D` is exactly the UTF-8 code of 好. So you may use this as a breaking point to implement your dictionary function.

Also, if your app is for commercial purpose, please don't forget reading the license of this website before using it ;)

Have fun coding!